# Trusted redirect response

Tags: 8

I installed version 8.3.7 and today the version 8.4.0 (NOT localhost, multilingual or not), using PHP 7.0.13, MySQL 5.6.22, and made the proper settings apparently. I read about this problem, which generates this error:

> Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it.

I took the necessary steps like changing the settings.php file and inserting:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = [
  '^gersonvagner\.com$',
  '^www\.gersonvagner\.com$',
];
```

However, the problem persists in all instances, for example when I try to put the site under maintenance or try run cron. I don't know where else I might be going for more than a week of testing and reading. If anyone can help me.

Every time I go to validate any action in the administrative environment it returns me with this message, anyway, the changes are accepted, but always this message is shown to me. Examples: If I run cron for updates, it runs and the message appears successful, but after the screen with the message I mentioned earlier. If I put or remove the site from the maintenance mode, the same occurs, that is, the site enters or leaves the maintenance with success, but I will only know this if I return to the domain and see the status, because the screen that always appears next is with this message: "Redirects to external URLs ...". This is repeated in all changes that are made in the admin environment, such as installing or uninstalling modules or templates. I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you using a `RedirectResponse` somewhere that is linking to an external site?

Comment: `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']` isn't used for `TrustedRedirectResponse`.  It just validated the 'Host' header in the HTTP request to make sure it is valid.  We need a little more information on how/what is generating your redirect here.

Comment: @Kevin, no, I don't do this, only trying to configurate simples things, how as I say.

Comment: @mpdonadio, I was edited the question, but I dont know what more I need to say... if you guide me with your doubts.

Comment: Do you run a multi-lingual site? - https://www.drupal.org/node/2643466

Comment: @rooby, yes. Three languages: Portuguese is primary, and the other two are English and Spanish. But before Im try this patch, Im using PHP 7.0.13, MySQL 5.6.22 and Drupal 8.3.7. This patch was indicated for PHP 5.5 MySQL 5.5 and Drupal 8, that is, by previous versions, and is not a official solution.

Comment: @gersonvagner the patch still applies to Drupal 8.3.7 and I expect it shold also work fine with PHP 7. have you tried the patch? Knowing whether or not it fixes your particular issue would help narrow down your options.

Comment: @rooby, ok, im try this, but the same problem to be continued. Im try too 
https://www.drupal.org/node/2863184, but not fix this.

Comment: The same problem occours in 8.4.0... oh God! Will be the server?

Comment: My foolishness! I just needed to uncomment 'RewriteBase /' in '.htacess'. I can not believe it was just that. I feel foolish, but I never forget this small detail. Many thanks for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, I just needed to uncomment 'RewriteBase /' in '.htacess'. Working now. I had forgotten this little detail.