# Getting error 'Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default'

Tags: 8, redirection, .htaccess

Getting the error after created this .htacces in root folder.

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/`

I want to redirect visitors to /web folder. I can login as Admin and enable modules, install themes and create content without any issues.

When a theme is installed, content created and publish it I get a blankpage with:

"Redirects to external URLs are not allowed by default, use \Drupal\Core\Routing\TrustedRedirectResponse for it."

I have trusted hostsettings configured like this in settings.php

`$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^my-domain\.com$',
  '^my-domain\.com\.web$',
  '^.+\.my-domain\.com$',
  '^.+\.my-domain\.com\.web$',`

according to this [issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/247004/trusted-redirect-response) uncomment `RewriteBase /` didn't work out either

Hope someone has a solution to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you still haven't figured this out, check this comment on d.o: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2612160#comment-11767977

It suggests a workaround by removing the subdir from the script name, adding to settings.php the following:

```
if (isset($GLOBALS['request']) and
'/subdirectory/index.php' === $GLOBALS['request']->server->get('SCRIPT_NAME')) {
$GLOBALS['request']->server->set('SCRIPT_NAME', '/index.php');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should change move the content of web to the root directory,
this a step by step to do it.
https://tecnovatorexperts.com/articles/fixing-drupal-redirect-error-how-use-trustedredirectresponse-external-urls

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.